# Whats the best way to count indirect function calls conditionally using cfg attributes?

Tags: testing, rust

When writing a test, I would like to know how many times a function is called, since bad logic may yield a correct result even when excessive and unnecessary function calls are performed.

To give some context, this is a tree-search function running a test on a fixed data set, however that isn't important to the answer.

I'm currently using a static mutable variable, however this means every access needs to be marked as `unsafe`:

```
#[cfg(test)]
static mut total_calls: usize = 0;

fn function_to_count() {

#[cfg(test)]
    unsafe {
        total_calls += 1;
    }

    // do stuff

}

#[test]
fn some_test() {
    // do stuff, indirectly call function_to_count().

    assert!(total_calls < 100);
}
```

It would be good to avoid having to put `unsafe` into the code.

Is there a better way to count indirect function calls in Rust?

Answer (score 1):

Mutable statics are unsafe because they're global, and could be accessed from any thread at any time.  The simplest solution is to change the definition of the function in question to take some kind of "counter" interface that keeps track of calls.  You can avoid performance problems by using generics plus a "dummy" implementation that does nothing.

```rust
// Use a callable because I'm feeling lazy.
fn function_to_count<Count: FnMut()>(count: &mut Count) {
    count();

    // ...
}

#[cfg(test)]
#[test]
fn some_test() {
    let mut count = 0;
    for _ in 0..10 {
        function_to_count(&mut || count += 1);
    }

    assert_eq!(count, 10);
}
```

You should really, seriously do *that*, and **not** what I'm about to describe:

The other solution is to use a thread-safe construct.

A word of warning: **do not use this if you have more than one test!**  The test runner will, by default, run tests in parallel.  As such, if you have more than one test calling into the instrumented function, you **will** get corrupt results.  You'd have to write some kind of exclusive locking mechanism and somehow teach the function to "know" which run it's a part of, and at that point, you should just use the previously described solution instead.  You could also disable parallel tests, but I believe you can only do that from *outside* the code, and that's just *asking* for someone to forget and run into weird failures as a result.

But anyway...

```
use std::sync::atomic::{ATOMIC_USIZE_INIT, AtomicUsize, Ordering};

#[cfg(test)]
static TOTAL_CALLS: AtomicUsize = ATOMIC_USIZE_INIT;

fn function_to_count() {
    if cfg!(test) {
        TOTAL_CALLS.fetch_add(1, Ordering::SeqCst);
    }

    // ...
}

#[cfg(test)]
#[test]
fn some_test() {
    for _ in 0..10 {
        function_to_count();
    }

    assert_eq!(TOTAL_CALLS.load(Ordering::SeqCst), 10);
}
```

Comment: Note that *a "dummy" implementation that does nothing* means that the code will be *monomorphized* and since it's a no-op, the code will act like there is no counter.